# What is the proper way to access the controller function inside the blade view - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I'm new to laravel. I want to access the `products` belongs to the `category`. There is One-to-Many relation between them. To get this data I created a function inside `ProductsController` named `getCtgProducts()` to do just that.

I know it a bad practice to query a database straight from views, hence I am writing the database query in the controller and trying to access it inside the blade.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**What is the proper way to access the controller function inside the blade view?** I'm using Laravel Framework v9.7.0

```dart
@foreach ($ctgs as $ctg)
    <h1> $ctg->name </h1>        // -- It is working. Showing the correct ctgs names
    <div class=container>
        @if (isset($products))
            @foreach ({{ App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::getCtgProducts($ctg->id) }} as $product)
                <h1> $product->name </h1>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

`ProductsController` class

```dart
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Ctg;
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        $ctgs = Ctg::all();
        return view('ui\welcome', compact('products', 'ctgs'));
    }
    
    public static function getCtgProducts(){
        $ctgProducts = DB::table('products')->where('ctg_id', $ctgId);
        return $ctgProducts;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't; the code you're calling in the `blade` file can simply be called in the Controller, and passed forward to the View. Keep your front-end and back-end code separated, unless you _need_ to, at which point you would use an AJAX request.

Comment: You might want to look into [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling controller from blade is bad practice
move your getCtgProducts() method logic to **Category Model**:

```
public function getCtgProducts(){
    $ctgProducts = DB::table('products')
      ->where('ctg_id', $this->id)->get();
    return $ctgProducts;
}
```

**Blade file**:

```
@foreach ($ctgs as $ctg)
<h1> $ctg->name </h1>        // -- It is working. Showing the correct ctgs names
<div class=container>
        @foreach ($ctg->getCtgProducts() as $product)
            <h1> $product->name </h1>
        @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

**Better way**:
Since there's one-to-many relationship
in Category Model you should have a relationship method:

```
public function products() {
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Blade:

```
@foreach ($ctgs as $ctg)
  <h1> $ctg->name </h1>        // -- It 
  is working. Showing the correct ctgs 
  names
  <div class=container>
    @foreach ($ctg->products as 
     $product)
        <h1> $product->name </h1>
    @endforeach
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I would suggest just removing the first part of your answer. Eloquent relationships are absolutely the correct way to do this.

Comment: @miken32 the first I wanted to refractor his code logic and the second is best practices part